# How to make a temporary directory that gets deleted once the body is finished?

Tags: directories, directory

Is there a way to temporarily create a new directory, then remove it when the body of the code has finished?

```el
(with-temp-directory path
   (write-test-files-into path)
   (other-test-functions path))
;; path is now deleted!
```

Similar to the Python function [`tempfile.TemporaryDirectory`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/tempfile.html#examples) by a similar name:

```py
# create a temporary directory using the context manager
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
    print('created temporary directory', tmpdirname)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`make-temp-file` can be used to make a directory instead of a file,
this example simply calls `make-temp-file`, then removes the directory afterwards.

```el
(let ((temp-dir (make-temp-file "foo" t)))
  (unwind-protect
      (progn
        ;; do stuff
        )
    (delete-directory temp-dir t)))
```

This same functionality as a macro:

```el
(defmacro with-temp-dir (temp-dir &rest body)
  `(let ((,temp-dir (make-temp-file "" t)))
    (unwind-protect
      (progn
        ,@body)
      (delete-directory ,temp-dir t))))
```

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Could you please add some text to explain what your code does?

Comment: Ah, the `DIR-FLAG` is what I was missing, I assumed `make-temp-files` was only for files :/

Comment: This would be nice as a macro `(with-temp-dir var ...)`

Answer (score 3):

```lisp
;; Inspired from `dired-create-directory` code.
(defun with-temp-dir (dir)
  "..."
  (let* ((expanded  (directory-file-name (expand-file-name dir)))
         (try       expanded)
         new)
    (unwind-protect
        (progn
          (when (file-exists-p expanded)
            (error "Cannot create directory %s: file exists" expanded))
          ;; Find the topmost nonexistent parent dir (variable `new')
          (while (and try  (not (file-exists-p try))  (not (equal new try)))
            (setq new  try
                  try  (directory-file-name (file-name-directory try))))
          (make-directory expanded t)
          (write-test-files expanded)
          (other-test-functions expanded))
      (delete-directory new t))))
```

Or if you want to do arbitrary things in the directory, not just `write-test-files` and `other-test-functions`, use a macro:

```lisp
(defmacro with-temp-dir (dir &rest body)
  "..."
  `(let* ((expanded  (directory-file-name (expand-file-name ',dir)))
          (try       expanded)
          new)
     (unwind-protect
         (progn
           (when (file-exists-p expanded)
             (error "Cannot create directory %s: file exists" expanded))
           ;; Find the topmost nonexistent parent dir (variable `new')
           (while (and try  (not (file-exists-p try))  (not (equal new try)))
             (setq new  try
                   try  (directory-file-name (file-name-directory try))))
           (make-directory expanded t)
           ,@body)
       (delete-directory new t))))
```

Then you would do, e.g.:

```lisp
(with-temp-dir "/your/temp/dir" (write-test-files ...) (other-test-functions ...))
```

Comment: Does Emacs have something like `mkdtemp` to create a new name?

Comment: I don't understand your comment question. Create what new name?

Comment: Are you going to morph this question too into one or two or... other questions? Bad habit.

Comment: Ah, I should have stated this in the question, I don't wanted to make a temporary directory that could potentially collide with an existing path. If this is different enough from you answer, I might be best to ask a separate question.

Comment: Define *"collide with an existing path"*. Your questions are sometimes not very clear. The code I show creates any missing parent directories. If you don't want that it's easy to remove that part of the code, in which case the code is much simpler.

Comment: Use use case is "give me a new, empty directory I can write files into, then throw it away" - Python has this - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6129600/432509

Comment: That's just what the code I presented does.

Comment: @ideasman42 See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Unique-File-Names.html

Comment: Not part of your question. If you want the directory name to be generated then do so. 
I assumed your `PATH` argument was the directory you wanted - provided as an argument. (A "path" in Emacs is not a directory "path" - it's a list of directories. What some call a directory "path" is just a directory.)

Comment: The call to `with-temp-dir` on the last line needs a `dir` argument, does it not?

Comment: I don't follow why this answer is so heavy when `xo6xu` 's answer seems to do whats needed and is quite short.

Comment: @NickD: Yes, sorry. Corrected.

Comment: OP: The answer is that your question is unclear - and apparently it does not express what you really wanted. 
You show a `PATH` arg, which I interpreted as the temporary directory that you wanted created (and later deleted). `xo6u`'s answer just creates a directory in `temporary-file-directory`.

Comment: OP: Your questions are often unclear, and then there is a long series of comments or changes to the question and answers, as you find your way and clarify things. We end up often with a still unclear question and answers to other questions than what you really wanted. It would really help everyone, including you, if you made more of an effort to figure out what you want to ask, at the outset.